New Site Design!
As you can see the new design just went live. Congratulations! Thank you for your valuable design feedback.
We have also themed the twitter account and newsletter template for this site, and adjusted the privilege levels to higher thresholds.
If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with "design" and "bug".
Congrats again and thank you for being an awesome community!
Oh! And by the way, we have also updated your Chat theme!

I was too fast for just about everything :O Thank you soooooo much for this awesome design :) May I ask which bits we see in our (new) background? And is there something behind the lower pattern in the background?

@SEJPM you're asking what is hidden under 010100... in header? it's something like "stack exchange is super awesome" or something like this :) we can change it to some super secret message for NSA though... or to anything else:)

@SEJPM: Specifically, it appears to read: OVERFLOW IS THE BEST IN THE WORLDSTCK OVERFLOW IS THE BEST IN THE WORLDSTACK OVERFLOW IS TH (and yes, there does seem to be a missing letter A between lines 5 and 6, as well as some missing spaces). It's not a cipher, just ASCII in binary.

Hey, Pawel, I like it as well. I tried getting some ideas of the modern look going and I'm very happy you all decided to go with that (and yes, I should keep a better look at Meta!). Cool stuff, thanks for the early Xmas.

@IlmariKaronen yes, the message is something like this, indeed. As I mentioned this is something I'd really like to have community input. So we may customize the message in future or even replace it with some other pattern (not neccesarly binary). btw Kudos for your, because I supposed you had to type this 1s & 0s to read it :D

@Paweł: Nah, I just converted it into PNG and ran it through Tesseract. :)

I like the logo more each time I look at it.

@Paweł how long should we keep this post [meta-tag:featured]?

@mikeazo i just removed 'featured' tag :) it's not needed anymore i guess..

This is probably the nicest Christmas present we could get from StackExchange/StackOverflow.
Thank you for your brilliant creativity, Pawel – I bet I’m not the only one thinking “I love it!”.

thank you for your kind words! really appreciate it!

Nice!
Once again, please turn up contrast on tags a notch.
 on Crypto  
 on Unix & Linux  
 on Stack Overflow  
 on beta sites  
I could use a bit more constrast on visited question titles on the front page as well.

I have to agree here, a bit more contrast would be very nice.

Yeah, I didn't read the post well either: "If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with "design" and "bug"....

I think you're right. I will increase that contrast in one of coming builds.

First thought that this might be related to the font issue, but since this uses 'Inconsolata' that's highly unlikely, so it's probably just contrast indeed.

Heh, now just "Nice" is left :)

Heh, almost didn't recognize it. Good work.
Thanks
